# Convert String to Postal code Format in swift

Tags: swift, string, range

In App i have string like

```
1A11A1
```

I want to convert it to

```
1A1 1A1
```

There should be space after 3characters.

What i tried is : code = 1A11A1

```
let end = code.index(code.startIndex, offsetBy: code.count)
        let range = code.startIndex..<end
    if code.count < 3 {
                code = code.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d+)", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression, range: range)
            }
            else {
                code = code.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d{3})(\\d+)", with: "$1 $2", options: .regularExpression, range: range)
            }
```

Comment: You could match word chars instead of digits only `(\\w{3})(\\w+)` and replace with the 2 groups `$1 $2` or `(?<!\\S)(\\w{3})(\\w+)`

Answer (score 3):

If your rule is that you want a "space after 3 characters," take three characters, add a space and then the rest:

```
let result = "\(code.prefix(3)) \(code.dropFirst(3))"
// "1A1 1A1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Rob's solution is fine, just for the sake of it, there's also an option to use `insert(" ", at: index)`, something like this:

```
extension String {

    var postalCode: String {

        var result = self

        // Check that this string is the right length
        guard result.count == 6 else {
            return result
        }

        let index = result.index(result.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)

        result.insert(" ", at: index)
        return result
    }
}
```

Test:

```
let str: String = "1A11A1"
print(str.postalCode) // prints 1A1 1A1
let str2: String = "1A1 1A1"
print(str2.postalCode) // prints 1A1 1A1 (doesn't change format)
let str3: String = "12345"
print(str3.postalCode) // prints 12345 (doesn't change format)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. but it is textfield. so it will not work when keyboard is getting back. It will only work for string

Comment: @iosdeveloper please edit your question and add this info there. What you are trying is to create a text field that would format your string on the fly.

Comment: yes, if it is a textfield, it's a completely different question.